# How can I redirect pretty-print in IRB

Tags: ruby, mechanize, pretty-print

I am trying to redirect pretty-print output in IRB but pp page >> results.txt does not work.
How can I redirect pretty print to file? I am using Windows OS.

**My code**

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'

page = agent.get('http://www.asus.com/Search/')
pp page
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect output to a file inside a Ruby script using `>>`. That trick only works at the command-line.

To write to a file use:

```
File.open('results.txt', 'a') { |fo| pp page, fo }
```

See the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html#method-c-pp) for `pp` for more information.

Comment: For some reason it gives me a blank results.txt file with no errors just the message #<File:results.txt (closed)>]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work, for anyone curious, this is based on another pretty print question I found:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'

page = agent.get('http://www.asus.com/Search/')
pp page

File.open("results.txt","w") do |f|
PP.pp(page,f)
end
```